# Calculating a simple transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, pnp, calculate

I have this circuit in the picture, and I am hoping to figure out the calculations/formulas behind it. It is a PNP transistor, is it possible to find out what the 'β' or the DC gain H(FE)? (EDIT: I did ask for h(FE) but as Antonio51 pointed out is for AC and is not what I need.)

EDIT:
like folks are pointing out (and thank you) because the transistor is saturated it's like a short circuit between collector and emitter and perhaps easy to calculate R3 and I(R3).

[image]

But Veb is only like 0.8V and I(R4) is mixing with I(R2), are there formulas describe that "relationship"?

What I'm looking for is something like in the picture below, just for a circuit closer to what I am having.
[image]

Comment: If you have Ib and Ic, you know β.

Comment: Don't misc  Hfe (DC gain current=Ic/Ib) and hfe (ac)=beta (ic/ib =incremental gain).

Comment: If you have Ic you know the transconductance gm and can immediately find the voltage gain between hte base node and the collector.

Comment: make sure the transistor's operating in the correct mode for what you want to determine.

Answer (score 5):

The transistor is saturated so you can’t tell much about the transistor characteristics under non-saturated conditions. The forced beta is just Ic/Ib.

Under more normal conditions (BC557 beta is specified at Vce = -5V, not -0.1V) we know beta is considerably more than 100 since it is well saturated with Ic/Ib ~= 100.

Answer (score 3):

```
You know    IE               =  9.96        mA      
You know    IB               =  0.101       mA     
You know that IC=IE-IB       =  9.86        mA    
You know that B = IC/IB hFe  = 97           mA/mA
```

This is the transistor gain when this value of IB is feed in the base at that particular voltage VCE.

In your particular case this value may not be very useful because the circuit puts transistor in saturation. If VC was higher like 4 or 5 volts you would probably see a much higher *B* value.
*B* is usually not a constant all over the transistor curve.

Comment: Except that IE is **not** determined by \$h_{FE}\$ in this case. Since the transistor is saturated IE is limited by R3 instead.

Answer (score 2):

As @Neil_UK pointed, I made a simulation with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip). EE&O.

I made a "calculation" with the BC557B. Here is what I found.
Quiet Point of OP "not confirmed", Vce= ~ -2.3 V, OP is -0.1 V).
Perhaps "bad" parameters (mine) of the BC557B model.
AC parameter "beta" measured (AC Analysis) @ 1kHz (Vce= ~ -2.3V).

[image]